# I need information about Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I need some information about the Informatica ETL tool. I am a rookie with that, so could you please recommend where can I get some tutorials to get started. Can I download the tool, and if so where can I download it? What are the alternatives to Informatica?

Comment: Did you try http://www.informatica.com/Pages/index.aspx/? I got that just by typing "informatica.com" into my browser.

Comment: @Mike: btw, why were you unable to find this URL?

Comment: Yeah, i found that URL, but i was looking for something little deeper, i got it now...thnx!!!

Answer (score 4):

Try [Informatica Comunities](https://community.informatica.com/index.jspa).  Be warned that Informatica makes it hard to find what you are looking for.  I have been using it for seven-plus years -- very powerful, but very expensive and poorly constructed.  Look carefully at open-source solutions, too.

As far as downloading, I vaguely remember something called a "Personal Edition" intended for evaluation, but I could not find it on their website.

Oh, I found it.  $500 for a "limited version" that expires in one year.  Look for "PowerCenter Developer Edition Request Form".

Answer (score 2):

Informatica is one of many ETL tools.  Ab Initio and SSIS are commercial competitors; there are open source alternatives.

If the vendor doesn't offer a downloadable version you're out of luck.  If just you want to try out the ideas, Google for an open source alternative and try it out.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Microsoft's 2005 ETL tool SSIS and Pentaho's Kettle (now called PDI), but not informatica. Of those 2, Pentaho was better than Microsoft and a free download to boot. So I would recommend adding Pentaho to any ETL evaluation shortlist.

Answer (score 1):

Try Oracle Business Intelligence Application (OBIA). They supply you with a numerous BI Aplpications, including PowerCenter. Used to be free of charge fon non-productive environments